# Azure Notification Hub App Logo for multiple platforms

Tags: xamarin.forms, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I have NH working ok, but I want to have an image accompany the push.  Basically, this image is a branding option, so it wouldn't change for each push, but could change occasionally.

This seems pretty straightforward for WNS, using the App Logo Override option.

Can something similar be done for iOS and Android?  I haven't played with them yet and I don't really need a whole solution, I just can't seem to find it spelled out like it is for WNS.

I did see an example for iOS that involved sending a silent notification that prompted the user to see the image, but that's not what I'm trying to do.

I just want a message from a particular vendor to have their little logo on it.

Is this possible?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the best way to do this is to send a URL for an image in the template and substitute it for the applogo image source.  Remember that when you do that, the system will not automatically size it for you.